# Changes don't occur because of node.js' asynchronicity

Tags: node.js

I'm a beginner at node js and I'm doing a simple project with pure node.js.
So here is my code:

```
if(req.url ==="/"&&req.method==="POST"){
        let reqBody = "";
        req.on('data', chunk=>{
            reqBody += chunk.toString();
        });
        req.on("end", ()=>{
            reqBody = reqBody.split("&");
            for(let i=0; i<reqBody.length; i++){
                reqBody[i]=reqBody[i].split("=");
                reqBody[i] = reqBody[i][1];
                };
            //filter country    
            let countryFound;
            if(reqBody[1].length>0){
                    let countryList = "";
                    let countryVal = [];

                    countryListStream = fs.createReadStream("./public/country.list.json", "UTF-8");
                    countryListStream.on("data", countryChunk=>{
                        countryList+=countryChunk;
                        countryChunk = JSON.parse(countryChunk);
                        countryFound = countryChunk.filter(elem=> elem["name"].toLowerCase()==reqBody[1].toLowerCase());
                        if(countryFound.length!==0){
                            countryListStream.destroy();
                        };
                    });
                    countryListStream.on("end", ()=>{
                        countryFound = "Not Found"
                    });
            };
        });

    };
```

My problem is below "filter country" comment:
when I log the "countryFound" variable outside of the events of "countryListStream", it displays undefined.But when i log it inside of the events, it displays what I want. I think it's becaus of how node.js is made, but I don't know to continue my code if it's undefined.
I think that I need to include a code that waits until the variable is updated, and then it runs the rest.
I tried with this after the if statement, and it didn't fixed it:

```
if(countryFound!===undefined){
    console.log(countryFound);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From looking at the documentation, calling `countryStream.destroy()` emits `close` and `error` events. So, it would make sense to add a handler to the `close` event where you can continue processing the values that you have assigned to those variables:

```
countryStream.on('close', () => {
    console.log(countryFound) // should not be undefined now
    // ...do something with your new values
});
```

Comment: Thank you, but imagine if I've added the same code to get "cityFound" var. How can I send the response when the country and the city are found?

Comment: You could emit a custom event upon finding the city/country, e.g. `this.emit('found')` (within the `data` event handlers), and in the handler for that event check to see if both `country` and `city` have been assigned value before continuing.

Comment: Thank you. I managed to solve my problem but it took a lot of lines and there was so many events nested in other events which made the code complicated.But i will try to emit a custom event.